# Creating a file with the name of a structure i just read from another file

Tags: c, file, binary, structure

I am trying to read a structure from the file f and i need some arrays of that structure ( "nume" and "firma.nrang") to be written into another file with the name of "localitate" which is also an array of the structure i am reading. 
If two structures from f have the same "localitate" array, then their "nume" and "firma.nrang" fields need to be written in the same file called "localitate". I hope i explained well enough. However, i dont know why i cannot open the files i am creating, which i specifically wanted to be text and not binary. What is the problem? 
This is my code which doesnt work properly:

```
typedef struct
{
    char localitate[10];
    int nrang;
} FIRMA;

typedef struct
{
    char nume[20];
    int varsta;
    FIRMA firma;
} ANG;




    ANG x;
    FILE *p;
    for (i=0; i<m+n; i++)
    {
        fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,f);
        p=fopen(x.firma.localitate,"a");
        if (p==NULL)
        {
            printf("eroare");
            exit (1);
        }
        fwrite(&x.nume,sizeof(x.nume),1,p);
        fwrite(&x.firma.nrang,sizeof(x.firma.nrang),1,p);
        fclose(p);


    }
```

Comment: You need to show the structure definition. Don't dexscribe your code, show it. Or best provide a [mcve].

Comment: One possible cause of problem is that you might need to open your file with the `"ab"` mode instead of `"a"` mode because you're reading binary data and not text data.

Comment: @JoeyMallone don't write "mcve" in a comment but just write `[mcve]` this will automatically expand to `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` with the correct link

Comment: So the program prints "err" and terminate! Is that it?

Comment: As OP is unresponsive to request for additional information, I'll vote to close

Comment: @4386427 no, the code works, it creates the files, but the files cannot be opened.

Comment: I just posted the entire code @jabberwocky

Comment: @MaryPoppins please show the minimal input that triggers the problem.

Comment: Okay. I just did

Comment: @MaryPoppins where is the input?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP won't provide the information he is asked for.

Comment: Checking return of fopen and fwrite may help.